# JavaScript expiration time - API Response

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, api, milliseconds

I'm new to JavaScript and I am trying this API, it gives me this response, and I am trying to format the time to count down. I believe this is in milliseconds, but I don't know what its referring to. I am aware of how to convert milliseconds to HH/MM/SS, but I can't figure out what it refers to: Milliseconds from X. I searched everywhere and cant figure out **What these milliseconds are referring to?** Thanks in advance..

API Response:

```
Object
data:"[]"
deal_expiration_time:1469396377 //<------------ HERE
store_id:107645
```

Answer (score 0):

That is seconds since epoch.
https://currentmillis.com/
`$ date -d @1469396377
Sun Jul 24 21:39:37 UTC 2016`

Answer (score 0):

Seconds since 1970. Since JavaScript works with milliseconds, you can multiply it by 1000 and use it like so:

```js
var date = new Date(1469396377 * 1000);

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();

document.getElementById('raw').textContent = date;
document.getElementById('result').textContent = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
```

```html
<div id="raw"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```